# Browsing files in USB device in android tablet

Tags: android, usb, android-file

I am developing a project for an Android tablet which has USB port.In this project,i need to browse the files present in the USB device when a USB device is plugged into the tab.

Does any one know about this,And is there any tutorial regarding this topic ?.Is there any sample code..

Currently I am using Android 2.2 , As per the Android docs it says that USB host mode is supported  only in Android 3.1 and above.Do i need to change my API level to Android 3.1

Please help...:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation provided on Android Developer site, it seems that USB APIs are provided from Android 3.1 (API level 12) onwards. Android 2.2 doesn't offer USB APIs.

In case you also have Android 2.3.4 device, then you can use 'Open Accessory Library' which is based on a USB (Universal Serial Bus) stack built into the platform and an API exposed to applications. Check out the link below for more information:
[Open Accessory Library for 2.3.4](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.4.html#openaccessory)

Comment: Can you give any link /tutorial /sample code..i am really stuck in this..And i also need to copy the media files from usb to tablet

Comment: I found few tuts/samples codes on the net. I havnt gone through those in detail. Will be helpful to u.
[link]http://resources.upverter.com/android-usb-accessory-mode

[link]http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html

[link]http://www.mirwing.com/2011/05/android-open-accessory-library.html

[link]http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/05/bright-idea-android-open-accessories.html
Check these n let me knows if it helps/works for u.